# How to compare a container and a initializer-list to see if they are equal?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

For example

```
template<class Container, class List>
bool isEqual(Container const& c, List const& l)
{
    return c == Container(l); // Error!!
}
```

And check by

```
std::vector<int> v;
bool b = isEqual(v, {1, 2, 3});
```

But error in my code. No conversion from list to container. How to fix the bug?

Comment: `return c.size() == l.size() && std::equal(std::begin(c), std::end(c), std::begin(l));`

Comment: The comparison is not the only problem with your example, `List` cannot be deduced from a braced-init-list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example, as currently written, will not only fail to compile because of the comparison, but also because the template parameter `List` [cannot be deduced](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.type#5.6) from a *braced-init-list*.

Either change the function to

```
template<class Container, class T>
bool isEqual(Container const& c, std::initializer_list<T> const& l)
```

or change the way you call it

```
std::vector<int> v;
auto l = {1, 2, 3};
bool b = isEqual(v, l);
// or
bool b = isEqual(v, std::initializer_list<int>{1, 2, 3});
```

---

To fix the comparison, as Igor mentions in the comments, use

```
return c.size() == l.size() && std::equal(std::begin(c), std::end(c), std::begin(l));
```

Or, if you have access to the C++14 overload of [`std::equal`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal) that takes begin and end iterators to both ranges, you can skip the size check

```
return std::equal(std::begin(c), std::end(c), std::begin(l), std::end(l));
```